# Respondents inconsistent answers - keep lowest answer when given more than one? in R Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

Apologies for a basic question!

I have a set of customer responses where people were supposed to choose 1 option, but some chose more than 1. For these people I'd like to keep only the lowest value they gave.

I can figure out who chose more than 1, but I'm having trouble keeping only the lowest value. It's a bit tricky because lowest isn't numeric - it's low, medium, high in the column names

```
#this is what I have
people <- c("Anne", "Betty", "Carol")
low <- c(1, 1, 0)
medium <- c(1, 0, 0)
high <- c(0, 1, 1)

df <- data.frame(people, low, medium, high)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution may work for you:

```
library(tidyverse)
people <- c("Anne", "Betty", "Carol", "Darrel")
low <- c(1, 1, 0, 0)
medium <- c(1, 0, 0, 0)
high <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)

df <- tibble(people, low, medium, high) 

df %>% dplyr::mutate(lowest_score = ifelse(low == 1, "low",
     ifelse(medium == 1, "medium", 
     ifelse(high == 1, "high", "no_response"))))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  people   low medium  high lowest_score
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
1 Anne       1      1     0 low         
2 Betty      1      0     1 low         
3 Carol      0      0     1 high        
4 Darrel     0      0     0 no_response
```

This mutates a new column 'lowest_score' by progressively testing from low -> med -> high if the column has a value equal to 1. If the column has a 1 then it stops looking and records which column the first 1 occurs, and if the column is 0 it moves to the next column. If all 0, it reports "no_response". Not sure if you anticipate this though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse method using `apply` to read off the name of the first column that contains a `1` in  each row:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(lowest = apply(.[,-1], 1, function(x) names(.)[-1][which(x == 1)[1]]))
#>   people low medium high lowest
#> 1   Anne   1      1    0    low
#> 2  Betty   1      0    1    low
#> 3  Carol   0      0    1   high
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell it to operate `rowwise()` and find the first value equal to one.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(lowest = names(.)[-1][which(c(low, medium, high) == 1)[1]])
```